# How to add locations to the locations box in VSTO add-in

Tags: location, vsto, meeting-request

I have an application which has its own locations specified. When adding a new meeting in Outlook, how do I add these to the locations box in the add-in code?

Answer (score 0):

You [can't](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/clear-the-location-drop-down-list-on-appointments/).

"Outlook appointments show a drop-down list for Location, populated with the most recently used locations added to appointments. You cannot populate this list with your own preferred locations..."

I'm guessing it's possible to edit this value to add your own... So yet one more supposedly impossible thing which is possible.